Custom response for timeout exception
I have set the timeout for my application with quarkus.http.idle-timeout=15S. And this works fine, if the request takes longer than 15s an error response is given to the client.
But the response status is 500 and not 408. It would be nice to have the specific http status for
timeout to handle it accordingly on the client.
To handle the exception and build a new response with the specific status code an ExceptionMapper was created. (changed the type from ExceptionMapper to the most generic one for debugging)
@Provider
public class TimeoutExceptionHandler implements ExceptionMapper<Exception> {

    private static final ShareLogger LOGGER = ShareLogger.create(TimeoutExceptionHandler.class);

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(final Exception e) {
        LOGGER.debug("exception mapper [{}]", e.toString());
        return Response.ok().build();
    }
}

For normal exceptions, that are thrown in a resource the mapper works. But for the timeout exception that is thrown after the 15s mark not. In that case the mapper is not executed and the gets delivered to the client.
Is there a way to catch the timeout exception and give the client a custom response?

Can you try it with @ServerExceptionMapper, see this link: https://quarkus.io/guides/rest#exception-mapping

@Serkan I tried it but it was the same behaviour.
I think I read somewhere, that ServerExceptionMapper creates an ExceptionMapper class in the background where the function is called in the toResponse.

Have you tried it with setting the priority to highest level on @ServerExceptionMapper ? And can you check in the dev-ui whether there are other exception mappers registered ?
